# What is the distribution of determinant of multi multiplication of some Gaussian matrices?

Tags: matrices, random-matrices, determinants, gaussian

I have a square matric $H = (ABC)(ABC)^H$ where $A$ and $C$ are complex Gaussian matrices with some correlation matrices and $B$ is a diagonal matrix with entries $e^{j \theta}$ on the diagonal  such that each $\theta$ is uniformly chosen from $[0, 1]$. Do you have any idea about the distribution of the determinant of this matrix, i.e., $\det[H] \sim {?}$